# Proxy error for Array.prototype methods in ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6

My code is here:

```
var target = Array.prototype.push
var handler = {
  apply: function () {
    return 'I am the proxy';
  }
};

var p = new Proxy(target, handler);
Array.prototype.push = p
console.log(p,p(1));
```

Error is here:

> [Function: push] 'I am the proxy' internal/process/next_tick.js:93
>           callback = tock.callback;
>                          ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'callback' of undefined
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:93:24)

When I assign a observer function to `Array.protoType`, I got this error. Where is the problem?

Comment: Proxy target should be an object, not a separate method. There's no need for Proxy here at all. It should be just a wrapper function for push.

Comment: @estus Hi, just copy this code into your browser , it works fine. but nodejs falied

Comment: It isn't obvious. If you're having problems with Node only, please, modify the question according to that. It is advisable to state what is the purpose of that, you likely have XY problem. Because Proxy is used to catch calls to several probably non-existent methods. For single method a wrapper function is enough.